# how to write a query in sql that show special column

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a query and this table is the result 
[image]

i want add one more column that show result like example

example : 
suproforma= 53 => new column=[jameradif[for row1]+jameradif[for row2 ]+ ....]

=>(12750000+1147500)

thanks alot

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please add dummy data with table structure and expected output so we can make any sense out of it.

Comment: If not to large embed pictures instead of only the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the new column using `SUM OVER(PARTITION BY)` as below:

```
SUM(jameradif) OVER(PARTITION BY suProforma) AS TotalJameradifPerProforma
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can assume from your situation you need an another column that calculated the sum of your `JameraDiff` column coresponding to the same `Suproforma` column.

I have created a sample query for the same.

```
CREATE TABLE soexample 
  ( 
     suproforma INT, 
     jameradiff DECIMAL(18, 4) 
  )
```

**Inserted few sample records.**

**Records:**

```
SuProforma JameraDiff
53         1275000.0000
53         1147500.0000
54         2504000.0000
54         2253600.0000
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT tbl.suproforma, 
       tbl.jameradiff, 
       tbl2.totalquantity 
FROM   soexample AS tbl 
       JOIN(SELECT suproforma, 
                   Sum(jameradiff) AS TotalQuantity 
            FROM   soexample 
            GROUP  BY suproforma) AS tbl2 
         ON tbl.suproforma = tbl2.suproforma
```

**Output:**

```
suproforma jameradiff   TotalQuantity 
53         1275000.0000 2422500.0000
53         1147500.0000 2422500.0000
54         2504000.0000 4757600.0000
54         2253600.0000 4757600.0000
```